# How to break down a string that's in an array even further

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to break down a sentence that's part of one string, but break it down into letters in their own array and have that inside one big array.

So what I mean is:

```
def break("hello world")
```

the code in the method would than result in this:

```
[["h","e","l","l","o], ["w","o","r","l","d"]]
```

The reason why I need it like that is so I can rearrange the letters in the order I want later.  I've tried several things, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use break as a method name. It's a key word in the language.

```
def break_it(str)
  str.split.map { |word| word.each_char.to_a }
end

break_it("hello world")
```

Comment: Thank you, it did exactly what I wanted it to do.  Also, I know "break" would be a bad method name, I was just using that one word instead of camel-casing the entire thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
"hello world".split.map &:chars
# => [["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"], ["w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]]
```

Comment: When I try to use this method, I get the following result:

    [#<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x14a99c>, #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x14a974>]

Am I missing something here?  I replaced the string in your code with a variable name, but I wouldn't think that would effect it this much

Comment: This will work with Ruby => 2.0. Unless specified the assumption is that latest version is being used.

Comment: Well, instead of running it on my system, I was executing the code with browser at repl.it.  Their Ruby section is still in the beta stage, so that might be the reason why the code was not able to be executed.